# Syncing Opera Mobile/Mini with Desktop Firefox

Tags: sync, firefox-for-android, opera-browser

I prefer Opera on Android but Firefox on the Desktop. Is there any way to sync these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not.

(Having questions without accepted answers just bothers me)